# How to change UItabbarcontrollers viewcontrollers array dynamically?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an iPhone application using iPhone SDK 3.0 . It's a view based application consisting tabbarcontroller. I need to change the viewcontrollers array of the tabbarcontroller dynamically.

I just done it using the following code:

```
[tabBarController setViewControllers:m_objArrtabbarViewControllers];
```

But it only changes the customizable viewcontrollers array, so I couldn't able to switch to a new view.

I need to know is it possible to change the viewcontrollers array of a tabbar. If yes how can I do that?

Regards,
Syam S
IPhone Devr.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement following code to your application.
I have given code of creating the tab bar dynamically.

```
tabBarObj=[[UITabBarController alloc]init]; //your tabBarobj in .h file
objFirstViewCtr=[[MyFirstViewController alloc] init]; // your view controller object in .h File 
must be #import "MyFirstViewController.h"
objSecondViewCtr=[[MySecondViewController alloc] init]; // same way your second viewobj
UINavigationController *v1=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: objFirstViewCtr] autorelease];
UINavigationController *v2=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: objSecondViewCtr] autorelease];

tabBarObj.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:v1,v2,nil];

[self.view addSubView:tabBarObj.View];
```